# I'm not sure of a way to go about this task using Python code

Tags: python

Using Python code I cannot find a simple way to answer this task:

> Write a program that randomly generates a 4 digit passcode, then gets
>   the user to try and guess the passcode. The code must then tell the
>   user how many digits were correct in there guessed passcode.they can
>   guess 12 times before they lose or, guess correctly within 12 tries to
>   win.

Please help write a python code for this task. The main part that I'm stuck on is how to separate the digits to check them without putting spaces between them and then using the split command.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you have a specific question about a problem you've run into, preferably with code that shows you've already done some effort and research, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: 4 lines of python code will do, probably...

Comment: @Alex throw in some `;` and voila a 1 liner ;-)

Comment: Ok thanks guys I will look for somewhere else to post my task

Comment: @Alex Someone told me that every Python code can be changed to only one line...and without `;` ;)

Comment: @Tim I prefer some readability, at least :-)

Comment: @Elliot: Just post some example code and point out what causes problems/errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are handling things as integers.  You can use raw_input to read it in as is:

```
response = raw_input('Enter your number --> ')
```

And treat this as a string.

```
print ("Your first digit is", response[0])
```